# I have a project I want to make public on Github. I was wondering if there was a way to shorten my file paths on my project

Tags: github, path, public, reproducible-research

The way I've always imported data is by reading the file and inputting a path. I have a pretty long path and was wondering if there was a way to shorten my paths so that instead of "C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/Data/Data/MoreData"
It's something like ".../Data".

Also, if people were to clone my repository would they still be able to read the data with that original path I have?

Sorry for the noob questions.

Thanks.

I tried using google but couldn't find anything except normalizepath which doesnt do much for me

Answer (score 0):

When you push your changes to your git repository you are pushing just the project and nothing else from your computer. This means only the "folder" where your project starts from is seen, so say you have your repo cloned to "C:/Users/Bryan/Desktop/Data/Data/MoreData" and the name of your project is MoreData only things in "MoreData.." would be pushed therefore nobody can see your file path.
In order to change your file path in your computer however you can just cut the "MoreData" folder out and paste it somewhere else or clone the repo to the other file path you want.